# Python Auth0 - example script not authorized

Tags: python, auth0

Need to enumerate users, I'm using the auth0 client located here - https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python.

I've setup an example application, and made sure it has Client Credentials grant type.  Via the example, trying to run the following . . . .

```
        get_token = GetToken(domain)
    token = get_token.client_credentials(non_interactive_client_id,
                                         non_interactive_client_secret, 'https://{}/api/v2/'.format(domain))
    mgmt_api_token = token['access_token']

    auth0 = Auth0(domain, mgmt_api_token)

    conns = auth0.connections.all()
    return conns
```

However at .client_credentials, I'm failing with . ..

```
auth0.v3.exceptions.Auth0Error: 403: Client is not authorized to access "https://MY_DOMAIN/api/v2/". You might probably want to create a "client-grant" associated to this API.
```

There's a doc associated with the error, but it is 404.

Comment: https .... in chrome-browser you need a fully qualified cert-chain - no idea about Auth0 , if you token is valid, maybe the error happens earlier because you do not have a fully trusted chain? *poking fog*

Comment: This is in an API, not a browser.  The get_token comes back fine, the error is apparently that the Auth0 is missing a grant, but no idea what that is.

Comment: Looks like the underlying error is . . . .
```
"Grant type 'client-credentials' not allowed for the client."
```

Not sure how to fix this on the Auth0 side, if that's where it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK is consuming the Management API via the client credentials grant using the `non_interactive_client_id` as the client id.

The error you are seeing is Auth0 telling you that *that* particular client id is not authorized to consume the API.

The Management API is a resource you can find in your Auth0 Dashboard under "APIs" (not sure but there was also a deep link such as `manage.auth0.com/#/apis/management`). In there there is a tab that should say something like "Non Interactive Clients" where you will see the list of all your clients and toggles to grant them access to the API.

After granting access to the API (and to the required scopes), your operation should work.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, had confusion between the app we're talking to, and the Management API.